# Ubuntu 8.04: convert PDF document to one JPG per page

Tags: ubuntu, images, pdf, jpeg

I want to convert a PDF document that spans multiple pages to 1 JPG per page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that imagemagick is installed:

```
convert -quality 100 -density 600x600 multipage.pdf single%d.jpg
```

- The `-density` option defines the
  quality the pdf is rendered before
  the convert > here 600dpi. For high
  quality prints you can increase that
  number.
- The %d just before the jpg
  suffix is for automatic numbering of
  the output pages 0,1,2...
- The `-quality` option defines the compression quality of the output jpg
  (0 min ... 100 max)
- The .jpg suffix
  defines the output format. You could
  use .png/.jpg/.pdf

*From http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5560488&postcount=20*

Comment: Works for Cygwin too!